# Time spent in network exploding randomly - (website speed)

Tags: performance, networking, amazon-ec2, pagespeed, newrelic

We are a PHP web app hosted with Amazon in Dublin. Lately we have had a very strange problem.

**The problem:**

**All of a sudden our site gets incredibly slow, sometimes to a point were it is no longer available.** This typically lasts for a couple of minutes and then everything is fine again. **It seems to happen randomly**. Sometimes it happens several times in one day and then we won't have this problem for a period of days.
We track our website speed with **New Relic**. In the monitoring I found that the **"time spent in network" seems to explode all of a sudden** (definition here: https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work#what-does-the-network-time-include). It is normally around 0.5 seconds per request. This value explodes to anywhere between 9-15 seconds. After about 10-15 minutes it goes back to 0.5 seconds.

**Things that I can exclude as causes:**

- There are no traffic spikes causing this (it also happens during normal load) + we have sufficient CPU and DB power so that small spikes shouldn't be creating issues.
- There aren't any expensive internal scripts running that are causing the problem.
- It doesn't seem to be related to external software being unresponsive (even individual pages that have no 3rd party components implemented are incredibly slow (they don't even have google analytics).

**What I think it could be:**

- To be entirely honest I am kind of lost.
- The only thing I can imagine is that the time spent between the application and the database is super high for an unknown reason, e.g. because they are in different Amazon availability zones for a period of time or something like this, but this kind of problem should then be affecting everyone once in a while and I don't really know how to solve or detect this.
- I have reached out to Amazon, but am still waiting for an answer.

Have you had a similar problem or any idea what could be the cause for this issue?

Many thanks for any tips.

Comment: How much traffic are you getting on those pages? Is it small enough that 1 user on a poor network could cause the stats to show this outlier spike?

Comment: thx datasage. We have a couple of thousand uniques per day. So individual outliers shouldn't be causing any issues + the site also gets slow at my end and my network is constant. So it is definitely something to do with the site and not just the stats.

Comment: With a couple of thousand uniques per day, depending how its distributed across the day, you might end up new relic just measuring 1 or 2 users. Creating a statistically poor sample. Is there any way you can segment performance based on where the user is connecting from? (Google analytics can do this if you are using it, but you may not have enough samples)

Comment: _"sufficient CPU and DB power"_ is a bit vague, could you add the specifics please, i.e. the number of EC2 instances and esp. their type? Also it sounds like you are using Auto Scaling and Elastic Load Balancing, is this correct? What type of database are you using, are you using RDS eventually?

Comment: We're seeing exactly the same behavior while measuring in new relic. We have about 8k uniques daily. We've monitored this behavior live. It happens even when there are only 50 or so users connected. This certainly looks like it could be outliers as a result of small sample sets.